# How to Check why JVM is not able to terminate

Tags: java, jvm, daemon, shutdown

I have a program which has reached the end of the spring boot run method but it still won't terminate. Here's a list of threads running when seen in Eclipse Debug:

[image]

Here's what I can see after pausing the Threads:

[image]

Here's the Thread dump

[image]

My program reads from a message stream which is shutdown properly and also uses H2 db which I believe shutsdown when program terminates normally. I am not able to understand what is preventing JVM to shutdown and how to go ahead in tackling this situation be seeing the list of threads running.

Comment: Looks like "Catalina-utility-1" and "container-0" are busy doing stuff. Can you pause those threads and see what's going on? They're possibly keeping your VM alive; the DestroyJavaVM thread will be able to forcefully kill the daemon threads without regret.

Comment: @NotaJD updated question

Comment: Womp I mis-spoke. Looks like DestroyJavaVM takes care of joining to all the non-daemon threads and the VM itself takes care of the daemons. That aside: are you doing anything funky with the container configuration or DispatcherServlet configuration?

Comment: I haven't touched container configuration or Dispatcher servlet configuration. will be interested in checking though.